# Is it safe to truncate these table (cache_hash, cache_pages, index_rel, ...) in Typo3 4.4 / 4.5

Tags: caching, typo3, typo3-4.5

I wonder if it's safe to truncate the following tables.

```
cache_hash
cache_pages
index_rel
index_fulltext
index_phash
sys_log
tx_realurl_chashcache
tx_realurl_errorlog
```

I can't seem to find reliable info on the web. The lowlevel cleaner didn't find much to clean.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way which should be safe:

Go to the install tool ("Install") > "Database Analyzer" > "Clear tables" and choose all tables (tick the checkboxes) and then click "Write to database".

Check your site. Done.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but remind clearing the indexsearch and realurl cache leads to a higher pageload on each page at first hit.